# Display error in UI of azure while entering parameter for ARM template

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-rm-template, azure-cloud-services

I want to display a dynamic error that shows up when a wrong name for storage account is entered(that does not follow Azure naming conventions) while deploying an ARM template. Right now i am taking input from user as parameter but no error message shows up. Is there a way to achieve this.
Azure has this feature as shown in the image below when we create a storage account but i dont know how to implement this using ARM template.

[Azure error when wrong storageaccount name is entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emQSS.jpg)

Comment: Take some time to read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the documentation. Post a minimum, reproducible, example of what you've tried so far to increase your chances for the community to engage with your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that this feature is not available for now in ARM Templates.

Please look at these feedback:

1. [ARM template parameter validation](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/38546242-arm-template-parameter-validation)
2. [Resource Group Template parameter validation](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-portal/suggestions/8622784-resource-group-template-parameter-validation)